# How does Alignment and Arrangement work in Jetpack Compose's Row and Column?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to set the `SpaceBetween` property to the Alignment of Row, but it seems has no options to match my need.

```
Row(horizontalArrangement = Alignment.SpaceBetween)
```

Comment: I answered that question in Medium and would be happy to post the answer here once the question is reopen. https://vitor-ramos.medium.com/understand-arrangement-and-alignment-in-jetpack-compose-7633f2ed5b39

Comment: The correct way to do this would be `Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween)`